# App Engine: What is the Maximum URLFetch Timeout Deadline in a Taskqueue / Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

What is the maximum timeout deadline for a URL Fetch on Google App Engine?

I understand that for normal requests, it can be no more than 60 seconds (which is the maximum length of the request). But what about backend requests or Taskqueues which can run up to ten minutes? There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805543/deadline-exceeded-error-even-with-a-taskqueue-running-on-a-backend) a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016150/google-app-engine-urlfetch-maximum-timeout-is-250-seconds-from-task-and-not-600) of [questions](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10470) on this topic with conflicting information. The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/outbound-requests#request_timeouts) is silent on the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60 seconds for both of them. It's specified in Java docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests#quotas_and_limits).

You may use sockets if you want longer deadline, but as I remember you [cannot use HTTPS](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11218&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) there.